# Android staging build type for Code-Push Multiple Deployment

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, code-push

According to Multiple Deployment testing in the Code Push tutorial, it is described, on Android, how to set the Staging key on the Debug build, and Production key on the Release build. However I find this insufficient, a Debug build will not run in the same way the Release build will  so shouldn't it be better to create another Gradle buildType for Staging??
I can't find anyone talking about this anywhere, am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I ended up setting up my `productFlavors` and `buildTypes` for a staging and live environment, along with debug and release builds:

```
...
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.your.app.id"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 5
    versionName "1.5.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "DEBUG", "true"
    }
}
productFlavors {
    live {
        buildConfigField('String', 'BUILD_ENV', '"live"')
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Your App"
        resValue "string", "reactNativeCodePush_androidDeploymentKey", "___YOUR_LIVE/PROD_KEY___"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
            appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        ]
    }
    staging {
        buildConfigField('String', 'BUILD_ENV', '"staging"')
        applicationId "$defaultConfig.applicationId" + ".staging"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Your App (Staging)"
        resValue "string", "reactNativeCodePush_androidDeploymentKey", "___YOUR_STAGING_KEY___"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
            appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_staging"
        ]
    }
}
....
```

And then some corresponding scrips we use in our `package.json`:

```
...
"dev-android": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js run-android --variant staging --configuration Debug",
"dev-android-live": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js run-android --variant live  --configuration Debug",
"build-android": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease",
"deploy-android": "code-push release-react your-code-push-app-name android -d staging --noDuplicateReleaseError",
...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you confirm whether you're still able to use `productFlavors` with Code Push? I'm unable to create a build variant like `stagingRelease`, combining `buildTypes` and `productFlavors`, and this [GitHub response](https://github.com/Microsoft/code-push/issues/560#issuecomment-373034244) from 2018 says it isn't supported. But it's been 5 years since then and I'm not sure whether anyone has it working now.

Comment: The [current documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/rn-deployment#android) shows creating a third build type for `releaseStaging`, instead of combining build types with product flavors.